# Функция сортировки массива и подсчет одинаковых значений

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, допустим `$array1`, содержащий значения:

```
$array1 => ('дыня', 'дыня', 'банан', 'банан', 'банан')
```

Итогом функции должен быть массив, содержащий что-то вроде:

```
$array2['банан']['сколько_значений_банан_в_массиве1'] 
$array2['дыня']['сколько_значений_дыня_в_массиве1']
```

Какая функция рассортирует `$array1` в `$array2`?

Comment: а что, сложно воспользоваться встроенной функцией `array_count_values` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php ?

Comment: Да может это и не сложно, просто я не знаю как это сделать, я только начинаю изучать php, и попросил пример рабочей функции

Comment: Как оказалось, это именно то, что нужно array_count_values

Comment: изучать язык надо с самых основ и хотя бы с небольшого осмотра и ознакомления с популярными общими функциями по работе с массивами/строками/файлами. А только после этого что-то писать

Comment: Ну я ставлю перед собой задачу - и решаю ее - мне кажется это идеальный способ изучить язык

Comment: Да, но зная уже некоторые базы и существующие функции — это делается проще. Согласитесь, поставив себе задачу прикрепить полку к вертикальной поверхности (например стене) и при этом уже знать, что нужны гвозди и знать что инструмент для забивания является молоток  — гораздо проще, нежели изобретать инструмент, который поможет преодолеть сопротивление твердой поверхности и поможет ввести гвоздь на нужное расстояние внутрь.

Comment: @Daddyman Да, ставить задачу и решать её - способ хороший. Но вы же ставите задачу и просите других её решить ;)

Comment: @СемушинСергей кстати да, хорошее замечание xD

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А можете просто написать в ответ вашу функцию и с примером для данного случая? Не понимаю почему вопрос закрывают, у нас простые вопросы разрешены.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov получив ответ на Мете о полезности простых вопросов не нужно теперь на всё подряд накидываться и оставлять  ;-)  ...... и это не то чтобы простой вопрос. Это основы яп, по сути. Это даже не практическая задача, в которой нужно написать свою функцию не используя встроенные. А раз встроенные не в запрете, то, как программист, при изучении ЯП надо прежде всего ознакомится с этими стандартными функциями.........и хотя бы помнить, что что-то подобное там есть.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я вас услышал, но всё равно за то, чтобы любой простой вопрос имел право на существование и не был закрыт. Даже о встроенных функциях и возможностях.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov всё бы ничего, если бы не было `Набросайте пожалуйста функцию...` как мне кажется..... а также пишет что `Ну я ставлю перед собой задачу - и решаю ее - мне кажется это идеальный способ изучить язык` - при этом не приложив усилий и, как заметил  Семушин Сергей, что ставит задачу автор себе, но просит остальных её решить..... кмк часть голосов из-за этого, часть от того, что это может оказаться общим вопросом и нужны детали и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вопрос можно отредактировать и убрать проблематичные формулировки. Комментарий вообще неважен. Можно удалить или оставить как есть. Но вопрос не стоит закрывать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov дерзайте ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Сделано

Comment: Накинулись на то, что ставлю задачу себе, а решить прошу кого то. Так если бы все решали свои вопросы самостоятельно и не было бы нужды в Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Daddyman ну так вы даже не попытались... вы просто пришли и сказали `Набросайте пожалуйста функцию...` а значит вы не себе задачу ставите, а остальным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array('дыня', 'дыня', 'банан', 'банан', 'банан');
print_r(array_count_values($array1));
```